# Как выполнить арифметическое выражение с высокой точностью?

Tags: python, точность

Как заставить питон посчитать выражение, например

```
(1/3-0.3333333333333333)*10**16
```

Нужно повысить точность расчета, но я не знаю, как это сделать. Знаю, что можно сделать через Decimal, но тогда каждое числовое значение нужно будет записать как `Decimal('1')` и т.д.

А можно ли задать точность более "красиво" типа `a = Decimal('необходимые вычисления')`?

Comment: Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону модуля `gmpy2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться модулем sympy.

```
from sympy import *
result = N("(1/3-0.3333333333333333)*10**16")
```

В результате получится значение

```
0.333333333333333
```

Вторым аргументом можно задать точность вычислений.

```
print(N("(1/3-0.3333333333333333)*10**16", 50))
# 0.33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

Результат будет иметь тип `sympy.core.numbers.Float`. Его можно выводить на экран, использовать в других выражениях как с методами sympy, так и в обычной арифметике. Получить стандартный `float` можно, применив функцию `float()`.